# Java Sorting a 2d array rows into ascending and columns into descending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Please, can someone help me, I need to sort my 2d array columns into descending order? I used this code to sort my array rows into ascending order but I now have to sort the columns into descending.

```
// Initialize array
static int[][] sortArray = new int[7][7];

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //initialize array values with random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < sortArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sortArray[i].length; j++) {
            sortArray[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

        }
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + "Before sorting");
    displayArray();

    //Print out sorted array
    for (int i = 0; i < sortArray.length; i++) {
        bubbleSort(sortArray[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + "Array rows in ascending order");
    displayArray();

    //Print out sorted columns of array
    for (int i = 0; i < sortArray.length; i++) {
        sortSort(sortArray[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + "Array column in descending order");
    displayArray();

}

// Sort rows into ascending order
public static void bubbleSort(int[] numArray) {
    int n = numArray.length;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
            if (numArray[j - 1] > numArray[j]) {
                temp = numArray[j - 1];
                numArray[j - 1] = numArray[j];
                numArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Sort cols into descending order
public static void sortSort(int[] colArray) {
    int n = colArray.length;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
            if (colArray[j - 1] < colArray[j]) {
                temp = colArray[j - 1];
                colArray[j - 1] = colArray[j];
                colArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

//  Print out arrays
private static void displayArray() {
    int i, j = 0;

    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(" ");

    for (i = 0; i < sortArray.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < sortArray[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(sortArray[i][j] + "\t" + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `colArray` is not a 2D array .

Comment: A 2D array would look something like this `int[][] colArray`, so that method will only work for a normal array

Comment: from what I read in your comments, you do have a 2D-array (rows and columns). Maybe you could edit your question and add some more code. What is `colArray`exactly? I guess it represents one column of a 2D-array, like `int[][] fullArray`? Then colArray would be: `int[] colArray = fullArray[i]` ?

Comment: @GameDroids I sorted my array rows into ascending order and now need to take my sorted rows and sort their columns into descending order. So, colarray is meant to be my method to sort the columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] colArray = new int[] { 2, 9, 4, 5};
int n = colArray.length;
int temp = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {

      if (colArray[j - 1] > colArray[j]) {
          temp = colArray[j - 1];
          colArray[j - 1] = colArray[j];
          colArray[j] = temp;
      }

  }
 }
 Arrays.stream(colArray).forEach(data -> System.out.println(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
if (colArray[j - 1] < colArray[j]) {
...
}
```

with:

```
if (colArray[j - 1] > colArray[j]) {
...
}
```

`>` instead of `<`

Answer (score 0):

First of all your array is not 2D :) , just because each elemnt of array has a number to be called like Arr[0] and its value is e.g 5 it doesnt mean its 2D.

but in order to sort your array into descending order you can use code below :

```
            int n = intArray.length;
            int temp = 0;

            for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
                    for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){

                            if(intArray[j-1] < intArray[j]){
                                    //swap the elements!
                                    temp = intArray[j-1];
                                    intArray[j-1] = intArray[j];
                                    intArray[j] = temp;
                            }

                    }
            }
```

Comment: also you can use Collections.sort() method to sort an array

Comment: Maybe I should have posted my full code. If I swop the < operator I am changing my arrays row into descending order and I need to swop my columns.

Comment: //Initialize array
 static int [][] sortArray = new int[7][7]; // this is my multiarray

Comment: //initialize array values with random numbers
      for (int i = 0; i < sortArray.length; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < sortArray[i].length; j++) {
            sortArray[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        
          }
      }
       
      System.out.println("\n" + "Before sorting");
      displayArray();

Comment: if i'm right you just want to sort each row elements by swapping columns. is it right?

Comment: I sorted my arrays rows by ascending order I now need to take these sorted rows and sort the columns into descending order.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your `sortSort` method to sort the columns. Though this shouldn't be the solution, but rather point you in the right direction.

This is how I imagine a 2D-array:

```
 _ _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_| <rows
 ^
 cols
```

In code I would look at it this way: `myArray[row][col]`

But more precisely its an array of arrays, so actually it looks more like this:

```
 ______________ ______________ ______________
|  _ _ _ _ _   |  _ _ _ _ _   |  _ _ _ _ _   |
| |_|_|_|_|_|  | |_|_|_|_|_|  | |_|_|_|_|_|  |
|______________|______________|______________|
      ^              ^              ^
     row 0          row 1          row 2
```

Each row contains an array of columns. And that's the problem - you cannot compare the array of row 0 with the array of row 1 and say which array one is "greater" ... unless you sort it by it's size.

In your program you called your column sorting method like this:

```
//Print out sorted columns of array
for (int i = 0; i < sortArray.length; i++) {
    sortSort(sortArray[i]);
}
```

The index `i` iterates over the rows and calls `sortSort`. So for `i=0` it takes the first row and passes the containing array of columns to `sortSort`. Thus your method can only sort the columns of a single row.

```
sortSort(sortArray[i]);  // sortArray[i] represents all columns of row i
```

To make it sort the columns, it must be aware of the whole 2D-array. Columns and rows. Meaning you can only sort the whole array at once but not single columns.

Let's look at it in my example:

```
public static void sortSort(int[][] colArray) {  // we pass the whole 2D-array int[rows][cols]
    int n = colArray.length;    
    int temp = 0;

    // since every row contains a whole array, you cannot really sort the row itself.
    // But you can sort it by its columns value (confusing, I know - sorry)
    // we take the first row as reference (colArray[0])
    // and iterate over every column (from 0 to colArray[0].length)
    // that's a problem, but we get to that later
    for (int col = 0; col < colArray[0].length; col ++) {
        // your sorting loops are working, so we don't change them
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
                // and here is the magic we compare row j with row j-1 of the current column (col)
                if (colArray[j - 1][col] < colArray[j][col]) {
                    temp = colArray[j - 1][col];
                    colArray[j - 1][col] = colArray[j][col];
                    colArray[j][col] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can test this code and see that it works. However it can only work under certain circumstances!

The problem I mentioned earlier is that every row needs the exact same number of columns as the  first:

```
This wouldn't work:
 _ _ _ _ 
|_|_|_|_|       <-- row 1 has 4 columns
|_|_|_|_ _ _    <-- row 2 only 3
|_|_|_|_|_|_|   <-- row 3 has 6 columns
```

If you don't have to make this work for a variable number of columns - leave it be. If you always have a nice table of n rows with each m columns, the above method does the trick.